# How to prove the below statements regarding the effects of zero-mean noise added to a sequence of observations of a random variable?

Tags: probability-theory

To more clearly state the question, let $$x_1, x_2, ... , x_n$$ be a sequence of observations of the random variable X. Add zero-mean random noise to the sequence and obtain $$ Q_1, ... , Q_n$$.
It should be provable for the following to be true with regard to the maximum and minimum numbers in the sequences:
$$E[max_i(Q_i)] \geq max_i(x_i)$$
and
$$E[min_i(Q_i)] \leq min_i(x_i)$$
I learned these when self-studying target network and double DQN for alleviating the overestimation problem seen in naive DQN. They were used for explaining the overestimation problem caused by bootstrapping in TD target calculation and maximization of the action-value function with regard to action, but I wonder how can they be proved?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming everything here is independent and the probability of ties is $0$, it seems intuitively obvious provided that you can get the notation correct. Let's call

- $\text{argmax}(x)$ the index of the largest $x_i$, so $x_{\text{argmax}(x)}=\max\limits_i x_i$
- $\text{argmax}(Q)$ the index of the largest $Q_i$, so $Q_{\text{argmax}(Q)}=\max\limits_i Q_i$

By construction $Q_{\text{argmax}(Q)} \ge Q_{\text{argmax}(x)}$ with equality only if $\text{argmax}(Q) = \text{argmax}(x)$. Then $$\mathbb E[\max\limits_i Q_i] = \mathbb E[Q_{\text{argmax}(Q)}] \ge  \mathbb E[Q_{\text{argmax}(x)}] = E[x_{\text{argmax}(x)}] +E[\epsilon_{\text{argmax}(x)}] = E[\max\limits_i x_i]$$ which is the result you want.  There is equality only if $\text{argmax}(Q) = \text{argmax}(x)$ with probability $1$.

The argument for the minima inequality is equivalent.